# Centred div which is going on the left if there is content on the div on the right side

Tags: html, css

I have one div which is centred and another one on the right side which may have some content. If this on the right have content in it, the centred one needs to move on the left. In the end the content from the two divs needs to be in the centre.

For example: I have a search box in the centre. If I have an result from the search - the result and the search box needs to be in the centre. So the search box have moved a little bit on the left.

How can I make that whit CSS?

Comment: Do you have some code please?

Comment: You have two divs. 
         <div id="div1"></div>
         <div id="div2"></div>
div1 has a form in it (search field) 
div2 has the result
In the beginning div2 is empty so div1 is in the centre of the screen. When div2 has some result div1 should move little bit on the left in order to make space for the result. And now the content in the two divs should be centred

Comment: Try something out and let me know when I can help. Stackoverflow is not a charity where everyone just codes stuff for you.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev: please edit your question and post the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `text-align: center` and `display: inline-block`.  Here's a fiddle with both elements centered: http://jsfiddle.net/rs6bmfq9/.  And, here's a slightly different fiddle with "text" div removed: http://jsfiddle.net/hrham7w9/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <input type = "text" />
    <div>
        Nam at justo dignissim, dapibus lorem eget, consectetur metus. Suspendisse vitae massa a nunc congue pulvinar non luctus mi. Nam turpis ex, laoreet tempor justo ac, cursus convallis urna. Sed eros ligula, congue ut lacinia auctor, porttitor ut quam. Nullam maximus, dui in eleifend viverra, est augue vestibulum est, id lacinia nibh ante vel velit. Aenean vitae sem ipsum. In porta felis urna, vel tincidunt odio aliquam feugiat.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > * {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container > input {
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.container > div {
    width: 40%;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```